# How to disable session cookies for a particular endpoint?

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I have Spring web mvc endpoints, and spring security configured. Session is enabled and the first request/response carries a "Set-Cookie" header.

But I want my one particular endpoint to not return this header. How can I configure it?

Comment: can you state what's your requirement for doing that ?

Comment: @NageshTripathi does it matter